# Understanding the coverage summary for dotCover in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, code-coverage, dotcover

I'm running dotCover coverage in Teamcity. After the build it constructs the coverage report in which you can drill down to individual class coverage.

I have a class containing 1 method that produces the following summary.

> Class, %
>   100% (1/1)
>
> Method, %
>   86.7% (13/15)
>
> Statements, %
>   91.7% (55/60)

Class and statement results seem straight forward but I can't see how to interpret the method result.

What have I got 15 of (of which 13 are covered)?

**Update**

Here is the gist of the class

```
    public static class MyClass
    {
        public static List<B> Bye(X x, B b)
        {
            List<B> bList = new List<B>();

            if (x is A)
            {
                // Do something
            }
            else if (x is B)
            {
                // Do something else
            }

            if (b.Something)
            {
               x.Where.ToList().Foreach(x => x.Work());
            }

             if (b.Something)
            {
               x.Where.ToList().Foreach(x => x.Work());
            }

             if (b.Something)
            {
               x.Where.ToList().Foreach(x => x.Work());
            }

             if (b.Something)
            {
               x.Where.ToList().Foreach(x => x.Work());
            }

             if (b.Something)
            {
               x.Where.ToList().Foreach(x => x.Work());
            }

             if (b.Something)
            {
               x.Where.ToList().Foreach(x => x.Work());
            }

             if (b.Something)
            {
               x.Where.ToList().Foreach(x => x.Work());
            }

            return bList;
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say it was 13 of 15 methods covered (or at least one statement executed in each method marked as covered/visited). If you can't see all the methods then remember that get/set of properties are also methods; they may also include the default constructor in that figure but I would have though it unlikely.

For most coverage tools I've used, I use statement coverage as my main value and method coverage(visited) next.

Comment: As stated in the question ... there is only one method in the class